# replace text in a line based on specified pattern using sed in bash

Tags: bash, sed

I have trouble to replace the text inside a line using sed.
here is the example.

```
<con:startTransactionRequestElement>2a07a832-5b4e-44d2-8826-64d8678f6226</con:startTransactionRequestElement>
```

i want to only change the content between 
`<con:startTransactionRequestElement>` and 
`</con:startTransactionRequestElement>` for example, change the above content to below:

```
<con:startTransactionRequestElement>abcdefegeawge</con:startTransactionRequestElement>
```

can someone tell me how to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking how to modify a string based on a pattern match?

Comment: Here is something which may be helpful: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/112023/how-can-i-replace-a-string-in-a-files

Comment: i am sorry if my question is not clear.
i just want to know how to replace the content inside a pattern such as replace the word between > and </

Comment: Here is something which may be helpful: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/112023/how-can-i-replace-a-string-in-a-files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
sed 's|\(<con:startTransactionRequestElement>\).*\(</con:startTransactionRequestElement>\)|\1abcdefegeawge\2|' file
```

If you want to edit your file "in place" use sed's option `-i`.

Comment: can i use variables inside\1 and \2 in your answer. for example if i want to use ${VAR} can it accept? i tried without luck. thanks.

Comment: Replace `abcdefegeawge` by `'"${VAR}"'`. See: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)